# Android Studio - how to use my wifi in order to connect to internet

Tags: android, wifi, emulation

I searched on how to get an Internet connection from my emulator in Android Studio and it was suggested I start up the emulator from the command line as follows: `emulator -avd Pixel_3a_XL_API_29 -dns-server 8.8.8.8`.  This indeed has provided an Internet connection when I do from the command line, after `adb shell`, then `run-as com.example.myapplication`, then `ping abcnews.go.com`.  this returns packets from the server "...r.cloudfront.net".  Looking up this server, it appears to be for Amazon AWS, and is "free", up to some data limit I haven't looked up yet.  This is OK short-term, but I would prefer to use my home wifi rather than go thru a different server.  **What's the best way to have my Android Studio emulator be able to connect to the Internet via my home wifi? (do I need a plugin?)** TIA, Steve

Comment: You do not have to do anything. An emulator will use the internet connection of the pc it is running on automatically. I do not understand your problem.

Comment: What I found was when I did "adb shell", then "ping abcnews.go.com", the ping worked.  When I did "adb shell", then "run-as com.example.myapplication" (needed to get chmod capability), then "ping abcnews.go.com", the ping failed.  This is why I resorted to adding the -dns-server option as described earlier.  However, I would prefer not to go through an outside server, thus my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, emulator below API 25 doesn't support wifi.

Second, you can't connect the emulator directly to your WiFi.

The WiFi in the emulator provides a virtual hotspot to which the emulator automatically connects.

So, best practice would be that you connect your PC to your home WiFi and then run the emulator on your PC.

Comment: A_Singh7 - thanks for that info.  However, as I describe in my comment to "blackapps", wifi worked after "adb shell", however, when I also did "run-as com.example.myapplication" (needed to get chmod capability), I lost Internet connectivity.  This seems to be an odd characteristic of the Android Studio emulator. Note: I'm running the emulator on my MacBook.

Comment: Yes, and ok. But anyways what you are saying isn't possible. You can't connect the emulator to your own or any other wifi. I consider the answer final.

Comment: OK - I understand on the wifi.   I'll have to contact Google as to why connectivity is lost when one uses "run-as ...".  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes. Surely. Do contact them and post the reply here.